# Icecast and SSL: auto .pem pass key (Windows)

Tags: windows, ssl, openssl, icecast

My stream works fine on both SSL and non-SSL, provided when I start the Icecast server (Windows), I enter the .pem pass key (generated with OpenSSL from my Encryption Everywhere .pfx file). That's fine, but if anything was to cause a failure , it would have to be re-entered manually so there would be no automatic re-start. (I use NSSM to run Icecast as a service.). So, does anyone know:
a) how to make it work without the .pem pass key, or
b) how to enter the pass key in the .bat start file (or somewhere else)?
Any help would be really appreciated, as most of the HowTos are for Linux.
Thanks, Mark

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use a key file encrypted with a passkey?

Comment: Not sure I know any other way?! When I use OpenSSL to produce the .pem file, it demands I enter a pass key...

Comment: Thanks for the input, Brad. As a result, I re-visited the SSL cmd lines and, sure enough, it's quite possible to export the .pem without pass key. Appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi, i just came across this thread and I've been trying to figure out how to make ICEcast on windows run SSL and I can't for the life of me figure it out. Any chance we could chat?